# How to specify printer paper size in mm instead of inches?

Tags: gnome, printing, cups, locale

In eog (Eye of Gnome) 2.30.2, I found no way to specify size unit in mm in `Print...` and `Page Setup` dialogs:

[image: custom size dialog]

So I have to convert these sizes in inches to sizes in mm.

I'm using CUPS as the print backend. Should I configure CUPS to switch to use mm as the default size unit?

The same problem occurred in Google Chrome 17.0 and many other applications, when I want to use custom paper sizes in the system print dialog:

[image: system print dialog]

Comment: What application is this dialog from?

Comment: Eye of GNOME 2.30.2. The dialog comes from system print dialog.

Comment: I don't use a GNOME, but in KDE are settings of measure units in the dialog of localization of system (Language, currency, etc...). Can you check, if there is similar dialog in the GNOME and try to search, if there is not a settings of measure units?

Comment: @Glorfindel: Thanks for helping to clean up broken images, and bravo for developing a tool to automate it. Can you please enhance your tool to use the standard image markdown (as illustrated above)?

Comment: @G-Man thanks, I can try, but it's not that easy. Sometimes <img> tags are used on purpose, e.g. for [side-by-side view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320669/295232). Since I'm [parsing HTML / Markdown with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/4751173) I have to be careful not to mess up formatting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Region Settings to a place that uses the metric system instead of Imperial system units (or US standard units).

How to change your 'Region and Language' settings in GNOME 3.3:
http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/3.3/session-formats.html.en

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how to fix it, but ....

If you install AutoKey-gtk, a keyboard macro processor (and if you know just a little python), it should be relatively easy to write a macro that lets you input in mm and have it convert it to inches on the form/dialog.  This could be triggered by a custom hot key that would work in almost any application or could be restricted to only work in certain windows.  You'd probably want to do the input inside the macro (python script) and have the macro send the converted result as if it came from the keyboard.

Although this is clearly not a fix, it does show a way to modify many programs to do things "your way" without having modify the programs themselves which often requires a lot of time and knowledge (and redoing it whenever the programs get updated).